# How to verify if user was deleted or password has changed in AAD in a Windows 8.1 Store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-authentication, azure-active-directory

I am developing a Windows Store 8.1 app using C# and xaml.

I am performing single sign-on using Azure Active Directory account login.

Case 1: I have added a few users in Azure Active Directory and log in with the  "User X" credentials in the app. When I delete that User X, in AAD, and I try to reopen the app, it is saying that User X is logged in, even though the user is deleted in AAD. After 1 hour it is asking the user to log in.

Rather than displaying that User X is already logged in, I immediately want to display log in screen to the User to log in.

Case 2: When I change the password of User X in Azure Active Directory, then reopen the app, it is not asking the user to log in with the new password. Again, it is displaying User X as already logged in.

In both the scenarios I want to display the log in screen for the user to log in.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have a couple options, but it depends on how you are authenticating against AAD. Can you provide a small code sample of how you are authenticating the users?

Answer (score 0):

Santosh, your application can try "polling" Azure AD for user account deletion, disable, password reset/expire/change, multi-factor auth enabled (and other) events. 
But I reccomend against it: Azure AD invalidates the refresh token automatically on those events and the next access token issuance fails (causes the user to have to sign in again). Access token lifetime is 1 hour - so the user will have access to the resource for at the most 1 hour after those events happen (except when the account is federated with on-premises and there is some time delay in syncronizing the change event to the cloud). Will you buy much by implementing polling (at the risk of it being buggy and giving a false sense of security)? Small time delay between account disable (or those other events) and actually losing access to resource is common in token based authn/authz - hence some security procedures require people to be escorted out by security when they leave the company.